# Significant difference between two variables given a third

Tags: anova, statistical-significance

Assume I have a number of subjects dividing into three profiles: 1, 2 and 3. For each subject I have recorded two attributes, age and height. First, I want to determine if there is a significant age-difference between the profiles. This can be done using a simple ANOVA test.

Now I want to determine if there is a significant age-difference between the profiles, given the height (as a covariate). How do I make this statistical test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working in R:

```
> require(car)
> fit <- Anova(lm(age ~ profile + height), type=3)
> summary(fit)
```

Don't forget to check that your data meets the assumptions for the tests you are using.

Comment: Should I check some additional assumptions here compared to just doing aov(age ~ profile) for the simple case?

Comment: Assumptions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_covariance#Assumptions_of_ANCOVA  Also, `Anova` in the `car` package allows marginal sums of squares whereas `aov` and `anova` default to sequential.